# Fortran runtime error "bad integer for item 11 in list input"

Tags: io, fortran

I receive the runtime error "bad integer for item 11 in list input" referencing the following line of code.

```
read(2,*)a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,theta1,phi1,k,l,m,n,o,
 $             p,theta2,phi2,s,theta3,phi3,
 $             r1,x1,y1,r2,x2,y2,r3,x3,y3,z1,z2,z3
```

The line its reading from is

```
1   255.11211   0.2876  165.11404   90  4   8   0.19173 90  165.11404   0.09587 90  345.11404   4   4   0.0764  89.99915    -64.51149   0.11131 90.0015 24.23892    470.10565   -454.32263  120.7902    264.91144   114.00389   -239.12589  322.2894    293.87778   132.3114    0.01236 0.00697 0.00006 0.42619 -0.19278
```

so a mix of integers and reals, but I thought this was okay since I used the * format descriptor rather than a specified format.

I'm using the gcc compiler.

Comment: item 11 is a float. *Assuming* you are using implicit typing, `k` is an integer. You can read integers into reals but not reals into integers.

Comment: Yes, I am using implicit typing. Why is k automatically an integer and, more to the point, how can I change it?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. I'll leave a note here for posterity about this. Because of implicit typing the variable name determines its type. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007365fbc/index.html talks about what letters mean integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item 11 in your list is `0.09587`, a real.  You are using list directed input, which for a real is interpreted a numeric value using an `F` edit descriptor (Fortran 2008 Cl. 10.10.3 paragraph 4).  An input list item corresponding to an `F` edit descriptor must be real or complex (Fortran 2008 Cl. 10.7.2.3.1 paragraph 1).

To fix this you need to define k as a real variable.  You note in a comment that you are using implicit typing (where variables starting with i-n are integer types and the rest are real by default).  To explicitly declare k as a real, use:

```
real :: k
```

Best practices are to disable implicit typing (`implicit none`) and explicitly type all of your variables.